# QML canvas drawImage does not work properly with AA_EnableHighDpiScaling

Tags: qt, canvas, qml, dpi, drawimage

I create a qml application where is drawing on Wacom tablet to qml canvas.
After drawing, I send the base64 image to the server and if I need it, I read it and draw it back.

Drawed image look good. When i looked image on server, it is in good quality. But when i draw it again into canvas is little blurry. If i save and redraw image repeatly, it is more and more blurry.

On HD screen it is not so visible, but when i use 4K screen, image quality is terrible.

When i don't use Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling is still in good quality. But without Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling is application gui too small on 4k screen.

When i disable smooth and antialising in canvas, image is not blurry but it not looks good.

this i am use for save image:

```
var loadedImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
```

this is for loading image :

```
canvas.loadImage(loadedImage)

Canvas{
   id: canvas
   onImageLoaded:{
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(loadedImage,canvas.x,canvas.y,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      canvas.requestPaint();
}
```

and part of drawing function:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(canvas.prevX, canvas.prevY);
ctx.lineTo(newPoint.x, newPoint.y);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
canvas.prevX = newPoint.x;
canvas.prevY = newPoint.y;
canvas.requestPaint();
```

How to fix drawImage when is AA_EnableHighDpiScaling enabled? I use Qt 5.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution;

```
  onImageLoaded:{
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.scale(1/Screen.devicePixelRatio,1/Screen.devicePixelRatio);
  ctx.drawImage(loadedImage,canvas.x,canvas.y);
  ctx.scale(Screen.devicePixelRatio,Screen.devicePixelRatio);
  canvas.requestPaint();
```